# Basics of a remember-me system

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a PHP / MySQL login system.  I would like to add a remember-me to it.  What are the basic mechanics of a remember-me?  Does it involve adding a new column to the table in MySQL where all of the user information is stored, etc. ?

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different methods for this. A <s>secure</s> method would be to add a field to the mysql user table and have a "remember_me" hash which is just a random hash generated.

The hash should be stored in a cookie on the users computer as well as the userid for validation purposes for however long the remembering period lasts (you should also set the remember me period in the DB as a timestamp as well for extra security). When they pull up your site, you see if that cookie isset, if it is then you just authenticate the hash to the userid. If it validates they are considered logged in. If it does not validate, then send them to a sign in page / they are not considered logged in.

This is how I setup most of my sites. The pain is that if they login from another computer, well they are now no longer validated on the computer they were using and will have to re-authenticate. But security, to me, is more important than them having to login again due to that situation.

EDIT:
See comments below for extra information regarding the sessions / security.

Comment: If security is important, I hope you're generating the hash in a non-predictable and also that you're not sending it over an unencrypted connection. And if logging in another computer makes you logout in the first... something is suboptimal in your solution.

Comment: Right, this does not go into seucrity detail too much. Sorry, I should have specified that. The hash should be randomly generated with a salt and a date in a unique way may suffice. If security is important, sending the cookies over a secured connection will be the most secure method.

As for the logging out on a separate computer, yea, it is suboptimal, but at the same time it does add a security layer in that it will make them re-authenticate a bit more often if they switch computers. Which means an accidental session (school) left open is terminated.

Comment: What would be a better scenario is having a table for the remember me and allowing multiple sessions for the user. Then when the user logs in, alert them "You have 2 other active sessions" and allow them to terminate other sessions instead of doing this automatically. I may switch my system to do that instead, I like how I think!

Answer (score 2):

> Does it involve adding a new column to the table in MySQL where all of the user information is stored, etc. ?

Not necessarily. A "remember me" works by storing in a cookie either the primary user credentials (his username and password, typically) or some temporary credentials that are set to expire after some time. If you use these temporary surrogate credentials, which are typically long random strings, you must add a table to your database where you store them, the username associated with them and the time where they expire.

You almost certainly do not want these credentials to be send over an unencrypted connection. You should store them in secure cookies, that is, cookies that are only sent over HTTPS (you should also set the cookie via an unencrypted connection).

If you choose to use a secure cookie but do not want to encrypt all traffic you can use two cookies:

- An insecure cookie that only signals the server that you have a secure cookie with the credentials.
- A secure cookie with the credentials themselves.

Then, when the user visits your site and he's not logged in, you check for the presence of the unsecure cookie. If it exists, you redirect the user to a HTTPS page. Since this is secure, the secure cookie, with the user credentials, is sent by the client. You then proceed to check the content of the cookie with that you have stored in the database and login the user.

Answer (score 0):

When someone logs in with 'remember me' set, generate an identifier, and store it on a cookie.

When someone visits a page on your site, look for a cookie. If they have one, look it up in your DB, where it should be mapped to a userid. Then just run whatever login functionality, just as if they'd entered a valid username & password.